# Retrieving the data from a text file stored in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to know how to retrieve data from a text file stored in the firebase using an app?

I am doing an IOT project where I have sensors, which will send data through the arduino board to the cloud as a text file. Different sensors will send different text files. So I wanted to know that is it possible to retrieve data from a text file stored in firebase using an android app?

Comment: Following links are how I learned to use firebase in my Android apps: https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352       and  https://www.kobo.com/gb/en/ebook/firebase-essentials-android-edition. The course is free, the book is not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Maybe the Realtime database is what you need?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Alernatively you could just use a shared folder on Google drive.

Comment: Can i retrieve my data from google drive using an app and sort it according to my requirements?

Comment: Yes. Once you have the relevant permissions it's just treated like a local file.You could write an app yourself or just use Google sheets or similar to view the file.